# Need help converting a script from PDO to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

Im trying to convert this script, in my Zend program.

http://github.com/jackmoore/colorrating/raw/master/rating/rating.php

```
<?php
class rating{

 public $average = 0;
 public $votes;
 public $status;
 public $table;
 private $path;

 function __construct($table){
  try{
   $pathinfo = pathinfo(__FILE__);
   $this->path = realpath($pathinfo['dirname']) . "/database/ratings.sqlite";
   $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$this->path");
   $this->table = $dbh->quote($table);
   // check if table needs to be created
   $table_check = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id='1'");
   if(!$table_check){
    // create database table
    $dbh->query("CREATE TABLE $this->table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, rating FLOAT(3,2), ip VARCHAR(15))");
    $dbh->query("INSERT INTO $this->table (rating, ip) VALUES (0, 'master')");    
   } else {
    $this->average = $table_check->fetchColumn(1);
   }
   $this->votes = ($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $this->table")->fetchColumn()-1);
  }catch( PDOException $exception ){
    die($exception->getMessage());
  }
  $dbh = NULL;  
 }

 function set_score($score, $ip){
  try{
   $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$this->path");
   $voted = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM $this->table WHERE ip='$ip'");
   if(sizeof($voted->fetchAll())==0){

    $dbh->query("INSERT INTO $this->table (rating, ip) VALUES ($score, '$ip')");
    $this->votes++;

    //cache average in the master row
    $statement = $dbh->query("SELECT rating FROM $this->table");
    $total = $quantity = 0;
    $row = $statement->fetch(); //skip the master row
    while($row = $statement->fetch()){
     $total = $total + $row[0];
     $quantity++;
    }
    $this->average = round((($total*20)/$quantity),0);
    $statement = $dbh->query("UPDATE $this->table SET rating = $this->average WHERE id=1");
    $this->status = '(thanks!)';
   } else {
    $this->status = '(already scored)';
   }

  }catch( PDOException $exception ){
    die($exception->getMessage());
  }
  $dbh = NULL;
 }
}

function rating_form($table){
 $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 if(!isset($table) && isset($_GET['table'])){
  $table = $_GET['table'];
 }
 $rating = new rating($table);
 $status = "<div class='score'>
    <a class='score1' href='?score=1&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>1</a>
    <a class='score2' href='?score=2&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>2</a>
    <a class='score3' href='?score=3&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>3</a>
    <a class='score4' href='?score=4&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>4</a>
    <a class='score5' href='?score=5&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>5</a>
   </div>
 ";
 if(isset($_GET['score'])){
  $score = $_GET['score'];
  if(is_numeric($score) && $score <=5 && $score >=1 && ($table==$_GET['table']) && isset($_GET["user"]) && $ip==$_GET["user"]){
   $rating->set_score($score, $ip);
   $status = $rating->status;
  }
 }
 if(!isset($_GET['update'])){ echo "<div class='rating_wrapper'>"; }
 ?>
 <div class="sp_rating">
  <div class="rating">Rating:</div>
  <div class="base"><div class="average" style="width:<?php echo $rating->average; ?>%"><?php echo $rating->average; ?></div></div>
  <div class="votes"><?php echo $rating->votes; ?> votes</div>
  <div class="status">
   <?php echo $status; ?>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php
 if(!isset($_GET['update'])){ echo "</div>"; }
}

if(isset($_GET['update'])&&isset($_GET['table'])){
 rating_form($_GET['table']);
}
```

How can I change this to Mysql?

Im using `$dbh = Zend_Registry::get ( "db" );` normally to get my sql access.

Thanks everyone, hopefully there isnt too many changes invloved

Comment: Hope you dont find this cheeky, I know people dont want to 'do your work for you' but I'm having trouble knowing exactly what to change, I reckon its about 4 or 5 lines in total, and of course you learn these things by example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the `db` object in the registry is one of `Zend_Db`** then:

`$dbh->quote()` becomes `$db->quote()` (the easy one)

`$dbh->query()` statements that manipulate data could translate to `$dbh->query()` (again, easy). However, it would be better to update the code to use `$db->insert($table, $data)` - or use `Zend_Db_Table` objects with `$table->insert($data)`.

`$dbh->query()` statments that return data can become `$db->fetchAll($sql)` statements, but you need to update the code to expect `Zend_Db` `Row` and `Rowset` objects.

I'd suggest reading the [`Zend_Db`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html)
documentation to understand the what functions map to the different PDO functions.

**If you just need this to work with MySQL** change the DSN string to your MySQL connection. Something like:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1", $user, $pass);
```

See the [PDO documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for details.

**If the `db` object in the registry a PDO instance** just grab that object and use it, instead of creating a new PDO object.

Comment: I dont know, Im still gettings errors all over the show, I thought the whole point of PDO was that the syntac remained the same throughout?

Comment: If you're trying to use a Zend_DB object, then you're not using PDO. If all you need is that to work with MySQL, just change the DSN string.

Comment: cheers, the script doesnt seem to be working all that well still, your new PDO shout was a good one though